# Odd string split in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have this expression "1=2,3=(4=5,6=7)" and I want to create a Hash out of this - 1 => 2, 3 => (4=5,6=7). I can do this in 2 passes. In first pass, I can transform the (.*) to something like (4;5,6;7) and then in 2nd pass do some split.

Any better solutions?

Comment: Could you clarify your example output Hash - it isn't in a typical Ruby syntax. Do you mean a nested Hash `{ 1 => 2, 3 => { 4 => 5 , 6 => 7 } }`? Or do you want to preserve the nested structure from the original expression `{ 1 => 2, 3 => "(4=5,6=7)" }`. Also, are the values in the expression always numbers, or should they be treated as strings e.g. `{ "1" => "2", "3" => { "4" => "5" , "6" => "7" } }`

Comment: `(4=5,6=7)` is not a valid Ruby object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you don't need to worry about nested parentheses, and
anything inside parentheses are to be treated as a plain string:

```
str = "1=2,3=(4=5,6=7)"

Hash[str.scan(/([^=,]+)=(\([^\)]+\)|[^=,]+)/)]
# => {"1"=>"2", "3"=>"(4=5,6=7)"}
```

If you need nested hashes, use a recursive method:

```
def hashify(str)
  arr = str.scan(/([^=,]+)=(\([^\)]+\)|[^=,]+)/).map do |key, val|
    if val[0] == '(' && val[-1] == ')'
      [key, hashify(val[1..-2])]
    else
      [key, val]
    end
  end
  Hash[arr]
end

hashify "1=2,3=(4=5,6=7)"
# => {"1"=>"2", "3"=>{"4"=>"5", "6"=>"7"}}
```

Note that this still doesn't handle nested parentheses properly. You would need a proper parser for that.

Comment: obligatory link: http://www.debuggex.com/r/ltye36gIFhLag31S/0